# Foreign Dual on USA log book?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, time, logbook-endorsements

I am a commercial helicopter FAA pilot with a USA logbook. I specify it's USA because it is in english and as you know with available entries to file that I believe mean something else in Argentina.

My question is if I can log dual time “instruction” in this book, because im a student working on a airplane rating.

Will this dual time count in the USA considering it's dual on a LV tail number?

And also any PIC time during required solo.

The problem is here for PPL you don't get a log book until you finish. But I already have this USA one and plan on going to the USA before finishing the rating or after.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can log it. From 14 CFR § 61.41(a):

> A person may credit flight training toward the requirements of a pilot certificate or rating issued under this part, if that person received the training from [... a] flight instructor who is authorized to give such training by the licensing authority of a foreign contracting State to the Convention on International Civil Aviation, and the flight training is given outside the United States.

You are only allowed to log training. They can't endorse you for a practical test or a rating or anything:

> A flight instructor described in paragraph (a) of this section is only authorized to give endorsements to show training given.